# Why do emojis print as weird symbols in my Java project on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, emoji

Displaying UTF-8 Emojis in java

I'm trying to print emojis such as "" in java on Visual Studio Code, but it would replace every emoji with a "?"
I tried to find solutions online and found that by importing:

```
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
```

I could print using a new printStream, which got me to:

```
 PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
 ps.println("");
```

However, this only returned unintended symbols "≡ƒÜó".
How can I get it to display the intended emojis?

Comment: I imagine you need to add a UTF-16 _encoding_ declaration as a _[launch option](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_launch)_ in the _launch.json_.

Comment: @Reilas Java may internally use UTF-16 for `char`, that does not mean it uses UTF-16 for source and communication with consoles and things (since Java 18 it is UTF-8 by default, before that - on Windows - it is generally a locale specific encoding, like windows-1252).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, is that what the launch option would be changing?  Only a JVM option?  I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in both VS Code and IntelliJ IDEA.

Please check your settings for terminal and file encoding.

[image]